# Unable to call a method with return type "IEnumerator"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method:

```
IEnumerator ABC()
{
//some code
}
```

I am calling this method from Start(), as:

```
void Start()
{
ABC();
}
```

but it doesn't run in any way. What's wrong with this? (Using Unity5.3 if version matters)

Comment: How does this relate to Unity5.3? Have you debugged code your?

Comment: So you claim `Start` runs but `ABC()` does not? - rally hard to believe in such a story. There probably more to it - you'd have to debug your code and provide more info for this to be answerable.

Comment: Hi @ Alexei Levenkov It is not hard to believe. Try it with a "yield return" in ARB().

Comment: @Jehof it doen't relate directly but there are several changes in libraries in the newer version. So I just wrote if in case it have anything to do with versions. as Alexei Levenkov edited my question.

Comment: @Stud sure... But I assumed OP provided [MCVE] - and code as it is shown in the post has no signs of `yield return`. It is somewhat unfortunate that possibly useful question missing reasonable sample code. Someone with knowledge of Unity3d may consider getting it in better shape.

Comment: @AffanShahab yes, SO wants to discourage incomplete questions. It is good practice to provide [MCVE] in "why this code does not work" question and this post definitely falls short there. I tried to comment earlier about it, but clearly it was not useful as you decided to complain about downvoting policy instead of updating the question. You may want to check out this META discussion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315018/why-are-stack-overflow-users-more-passionate-about-so-than-helping-people about goals of SO and answerers there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unity IEnumerator are most likely used for coroutines. They are called with:

```
void Start(){
     StartCoroutine(ABC());
}
```

Your coroutine implementation requires a return point where the method returns control to the main thread.

```
IEnumerator ABC()
{
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. If you call a function that has a "yield return" without using StartCoroutine, nothing will happen.

Comment: They are many ways to return from the coroutine. I won't list them here, some can be found here :http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html or here https://unitygem.wordpress.com/coroutines/

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Yes I had yield return. Thought it won't be necessary to show.